# Addition of two very long integers

Tags: java

For practice, I am trying to add two very long integers by placing them in arrays and adding the corresponding elements in the arrays. However, when trying to add the carry over, I'm having problems (I.e., the carry over is the 1, that for instance, you add to the tens place when you do 199 + 199 = 398).

When doing 167 + 189 I get the right answer which is 356. However, for this very example though (199 + 199), I'm getting 288 instead of 398. My question is, why do I get an incorrect answer when I do 199 + 199, if the carry over works well when I do 167 + 189?

```
if (stringNumOneLength == stringNumTwoLength)
    {   int answer; 
        int carryOver = 0;
        int answerArray[] = new int[stringNumOneLength + 1];
        for (int i = 1; i <= stringNumTwoLength; i = i + 1)
        {            
            answer = Character.getNumericValue(stringNumOne.charAt(stringNumOneLength - i)) + Character.getNumericValue(stringNumTwo.charAt(stringNumTwoLength - i) + carryOver);
            System.out.println(answer);
            if (answer >= 10)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j = j + 1)
                {
                    if (10 + j == answer) 
                    {
                        carryOver = 1;
                        answer = j;
                        System.out.println("The carryover is " + carryOver + ".");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                carryOver = 0;
            }

            answerArray[stringNumOneLength + 1 - i] = answer;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(answerArray));
    }
```

The output is the following:

[1, 9, 9]

[1, 9, 9]

18

The carryover is 1.

8

2

[0, 2, 8, 8]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parenthesis on this line:

```
answer = Character.getNumericValue(stringNumOne.charAt(stringNumOneLength - i)) + Character.getNumericValue(stringNumTwo.charAt(stringNumTwoLength - i) + carryOver);
```

are wrong. Notice how the `+ carryOver` is within the call to Character.getNumericValue.

Comment: It's pretty annoying to spend an hour and a half trying to figure out why all of the other cases except 199 + 199 work, only to find out that it was because of a parenthesis. Thank you so much though! I'll never forget to check syntax from now on. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You're adding the carry to the character rather than to its value:

```
 ... + Character.getNumericValue(stringNumTwo.charAt(stringNumTwoLength - i) + carryOver);
```

You want to move the right parent inside the +.

Note your for loop is unnecessary.  This does the same thing:

```
if (answer >= 10)
{
    answer -= 10;
    carryOver = 1;
    System.out.println("The carryover is 1.");
}
else ...
```

In case you're interested in an idiomatic solution:

```
public class Test {

    public String add(String a, String b) {
        StringBuilder r = new StringBuilder();
        int carry = 0;
        for (int ia = a.length() - 1, ib = b.length() - 1; ia >= 0 || ib >= 0; ia--, ib--) {
            int aDigit = ia < 0 ? 0 : Character.getNumericValue(a.charAt(ia));
            int bDigit = ib < 0 ? 0 : Character.getNumericValue(b.charAt(ib));
            int sum = carry + aDigit + bDigit;
            if (sum >= 10) {
                sum -= 10;
                carry = 1;
            }
            else {
                carry = 0;
            }
            r.append(Character.forDigit(sum, 10));
        }
        if (carry > 0) {
            r.append('1');
        }
        return r.reverse().toString();
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("789 + 89 = " + add("789", "89"));
        System.out.println("12 + 128 = " + add("12", "128"));
        System.out.println("999 + 999 = " + add("999", "999"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the answer -= 10 did the same thing that my for loop was doing and its much more elegant.